# How to check health check if the spring boot application depends on more than one data source?

Tags: spring-boot, health-check

Our application depends on 3 different data sources and we have to do the health check only for the database.  (I know we can disable few health checks (other then DB) from application yml file, but i don't want to do that).

I have added the below code to check what are all the contributors are auto configured. So that i can get the health status from the contributor.

```
@Autowired
    private List<HealthContributor> healthContributorList;
private void getHealthStatus() {
    healthContributorList.forEach(contributor -> {
    System.out.println("contributor:"+ contributor.getClass().getSimpleName());
    });
}
```

But its not showing the **DataSourceHealthIndicator** . it listing only the below indicators.

Since we have multiple data sources, Does the DB status comes under the CompositeHealthContributorMapAdapter ?

How can i get the health status from the CompositeHealthContributorMapAdapter?

```
ConfigServerHealthIndicator
RabbitHealthIndicator
BindersHealthContributor
DiskSpaceHealthIndicator
PingHealthIndicator
CompositeHealthContributorMapAdapter
CompositeHealthContributorMapAdapter
RefreshScopeHealthIndicator
DiscoveryCompositeHealthContributor
```

But the actuator/health (Showdetails=true) endpoint is showing the database health details as expected.

```
"db": {
            "status": "UP",
            "components": {
                "DataSource1": {
                    "status": "UP",
                    "details": {
                        "database": "MySQL",
                        "validationQuery": "isValid()"
                    }
                },
                "DataSource2": {
                    "status": "UP",
                    "details": {
                        "database": "MySQL",
                        "validationQuery": "isValid()"
                    }
                },
                "DataSource3": {
                    "status": "UP",
                    "details": {
                        "database": "MySQL",
                        "validationQuery": "isValid()"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

I need to get the DB health status from the HealthContributor bean.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to create class and implements MeterBinder, using the bindTo method to map each HealthIndicator.
[Micrometer gauge never gets updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58919095/micrometer-gauge-never-gets-updated/58951336#58951336)